# What happens to a Bitmap in a PictureBox once Image is set to another Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

If I have some `Bitmap bmp1` and set a `PictureBox.Image` to this `bmp1` then sometime later set it to `Bitmap bmp2`, is `bmp1` properly disposed of by `PictureBox` or do I need to keep a reference to `bmp1` and `Dispose` of it once I change `Image` to `bmp2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PictureBox` can't know whether you want the image disposed--you might be using it elsewhere in your app.  So it doesn't explicitly `Dispose` it.  If the `PictureBox` held the last reference to it, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, and `Dispose` will be called as part of finalization, but when that happens is up to the garbage collector.  In the meantime, the not-yet-disposed `Bitmap` is consuming unmanaged resources and most likely holding a stream open that will prevent modifications to the source file, so letting things get cleaned up "whenever" is bad practice.

If you know you're done with the `Bitmap` at the time of changing what `PictureBox.Image` points to, add an extra couple lines right there to dispose of the old one and you're done:

```
Image tmp = myPictureBox.Image;
myPictureBox.Image = newImage;
if (tmp != null)
{
    tmp.Dispose();
}
```